# How to combine duplicate values in dictionary into one value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have dictionary with duplicate values. How to join this duplicate values into one value
Example:

```
 Accord - first
 Accord.s - first
```

I want to see something like:

```
 Accord, Accord.s - first
```

Comment: What are the types that you're storing in the dictionary ?Please show complete example of your code

Comment: var Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood you right, you have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> source = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
  {"Accord", "first"},
  {"Accord.s", "first"},
  {"Gamma", "second"}, 
};
```

and you want to *group* by `Value`, which you can do with a help of *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 // If you want to create a dictionary:
 Dictionary<string, string> result = source
   .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
   .ToDictionary(
      chunk => string.Join(", ", chunk.Select(pair => pair.Key)),
      chunk => chunk.Key);

 string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
   .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} : {pair.Value}"));

 Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Accord, Accord.s : first
Gamma : second
```

In case you want just a query (not dictionary)

```
var result = source
   .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
   .Select(chunk => new {
      Key   = string.Join(", ", chunk.Select(pair => pair.Key)),
      Value = chunk.Key});

// and then
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
   .Select(pair => $"{pair.Key} : {pair.Value}"));
```